# If $p$ is a prime where $p=4k+3$ and $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then exactly one if its roots is a QR modulo $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I recall encountering a theorem which stated something like: if $p$ is a prime of the form $p=4k+3$ and $a$ is a quadratic residue (QR) modulo $p$, then exactly one if its roots is a QR modulo $p$.

I tried proving this to myself using the fact that $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=1$ (because it's a QR), which leads to $a^{k+1}$ being one of $a$'s roots, but I can't see how to proceed from here. Assuming this statement is correct, how can I complete the proof? (or, is there a resource I can refer to?).

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  is $-1$ a square $\pmod p$?

Comment: No, but I still can't see how this helps :/

Comment: Well...let's do an example.  The square roots of $2\pmod 7$ are $\pm 3$, right?  There's that $-1$.....

Comment: OK - I think I see it now (finally...): If $b, -b$ are $a$'s roots, and both are QR, then $b\equiv x^2$ and $-b\equiv y^2$. This means $-x^2\equiv y^2$ which in turn means $-1 \equiv y^2x^{-2}$, which contradicts $-1$ not being a QR.

Comment: Well, that (correctly) shows that both roots can't be squares.  To see that  one root must be a square, note that the product of two non-squares is a square.

Comment: Thanks for the instructive guidance :)